# KMS Encryption - Local Development

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I have created AWS KMS Keys for encryption / decryption. The access has been provided to a specific which can encrypt / decrypt. I usually attach this role to my lambda in order to perform encryption / decryption. However I run the code locally , it fails as KMS key doesn't seem the associated role to authorize the operation. Is there a way I could use the KMS keys generated for local development?

Comment: KMS is region specific. Are you specifying the region when accessing the KMS key? Also both services (KMS and the service (S3?) must be in the same region. KMS keys are not shared across regions.

Comment: Yes , I am providing the region. But KMS key was granted access to a specific role in AWS account. However when I run my local machine , I don't see a way to attach that role to use KMS. The same code works fine if I deploy it as AWS lambda and attach the required role to the lambda.

Comment: What is the KMS Key Policy for the key that you want to use for encrypt / decrypt? Add this to your question so that you can format the policy correcly.

Comment: In the KMS Console are you enabled to access the key? This is located under `Key policy` -> `Key users`.

Answer (score 0):

We recommend using different KMS CMKs for your development stack than your production stack.

As for why you are getting access denied, John is correct; that will be because the user/role you are using locally does not have permissions to use  the key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/control-access-overview.html